# laravel5でfacebookのSDKを使用時にsessionのエラーになる

Tags: laravel, facebook-php-sdk

現在、laravel5上でfacebookログインなどを実装するためにfacebookのPHP SDKを利用して実装を試みております。
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/5.0.0
こちらを参考に進めているのですが、どうもlaravelでのsessionの実装の仕方とSDKでの実装の仕方が異なっているのか、エラーとなってしまいます。
以下エラーメッセージです。

```
FacebookSDKException in FacebookSessionPersistentDataHandler.php line 50:
Sessions are not active. Please make sure session_start() is at the top of your script.
```

参考になるような記事はないかと色々と調べてみたのですが、上手く出てこなくてこちらに投稿させて頂きました。
ご教示頂けたらと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LaravelはSessionを独自で作っている関係でsession_startは行われてないようです。
もし、sessionを使いたい場合は、先にsession_start()を行うか、

https://github.com/SammyK/LaravelFacebookSdk

上記のようなライブラリを利用して実装すると良いと思います。